# how to configure a URL rewrite without affecting Web services

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, web-services

I am trying to configure IIS 8.5 to redirect to SSL, without redirecting web services that come in on other ports. I have been reading about this for days on various sites, and found excellent instructions and tutorials for setting up the cert and the redirect, like this link.

[config SSL in IIS 8.5](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8.htm)

But I have not been able to find anything about exceptions to avoid redirecting web service traffic.

If anyone knows of a good source or tutorial, or could point to some settings to consider?

I have the URL Rewrite rule written for {https} but I am little sketchy as to whether or not there is some way to add exceptions so the Web Service ports are not also redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web services are all on separate ports from the traffic you want to redirect(e.g. webservice1 is always called using port 81) then you can add a condition for your URL Rewrite rule to check that {SERVER_PORT} matches the port you are interested in rewriting.

If the web services are expected to respond on port 80 as well then you can exclude each by creating a condition on {URL} to check that it does not match the pattern for each web service.

E.g. WebService1 has an address of /WebService1/service.svc. The condition is configured so that the {URL} does not match the pattern of ^/WebService1/.* with Ignore case turned on. This should prevent it from matching the web service.
WebService2 has an address of /WebService2/service2.svc. The pattern for this ones condition rule will be ^/WebService2/.* again with Ignore case turned on.

Comment: I wrote the rule like this.... <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="1010" negate="true"\>   and it worked.